# Rendering HTML page preview

Tags: jquery, html, css, preview

I would like to show a preview of a full HTML page in an element on another page.
The whole page should be shown in a small 200x200 . What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: This description tells exactly what I want to do.
Show HTML page x, in a 200px by 200px div on page y, showing all the content of page x (like a preview). I'm not looking for a way to load the HTML of page x, just CSS on how to show the full page in a small div.

Comment: Please provide your snippet code that you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you could do something like:

```
$("div selector").load("url-location-other-page.html", function() {
  alert("Showing a nice message after loading has finished.");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Please check this out :

```css
.preview {
    width:600px; height:400px;
    -webkit-transform:scale(.25);
    -ms-transform:scale(.5);
    transform:scale(.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0; 
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0; 
    transform-origin:0 0; 
    border:4px solid blue;
    margin:0 0 -300px 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="preview" src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: @Erik "I understand how to load the content into an iframe or a div. My challenge is to scale it correctly in order to show a full page preview in a small div." This should be the accepted answer then.